# why my curve shape become smaller than original source curve?

Tags: modeling

why my curve shape become smaller than original source curve?
How to fix it?
[image]
Blend file here:
[image]

Comment: Attach the file please.

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: By this: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  From the image, it seems that the curve resolution is not quite enough to present that bevel detail.

Comment: here the blend file...
[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1790" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1790/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Curve control point's Radius ≠  1

Each control point has a parameter called *Radius* that controls the size of the object being beveled in the area of influence of that control point. You can see from the image sequence below how the parameter can be varied to alter the size of the section without a taper object.

[image]

In your specific case, the *Mean Radius* of the curve that can be seen in the Transform section of the Property Shelf is saying that the average *Radius* is different than 1 (size untouched).

[image]

By examining each control point you can see that none of them is set to 1, that's why the size of the beveling object is different from what expected.

The solution consist in restoring the *Radius* to **1** by calling the **Set Curve Radius** operator while all the control points selected in edit mode.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's right Carlo

Answer (score 0):

I think its because some of the dimension is lost while you apply the curve modifier. What you can do is try increasing size along any one axis to see if that works for you.

Comment: hmm... but I'm not applying the modifer.
the curve window frame is fresh curve, and when I use other curve as object bevel, it become smaller, so what I can do now is scale it up the source curve so the window frame become correct size.

wait, Im still editing, I accidentally press enter button :(

but, I tried using new curve, I create new curve, and it size correct (not smaller)
or, is that bug?